# scalatest custom order/sorted matcher

Tags: scala, sorting, scalatest

Does a matcher exist that would allow checking the order?

For instance passing in an `implicit scala.math.Ordering` to check if a list is `_reverse_ sorted`? A custom ordering would also make sense for other cases, such as checking timestamps taking into account the timezone (absolute time) as opposed to just looking at the time, regardless of timezone (relative time).

Also, what does the `sorted` word in scala use to detremine ordering? Does it use `scala.math.Order`? I tried to look in the source code but couldn't find the DSL interpreter.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you would like to test?

Comment: The two examples above: that a list is in descending order i.e. equivalent to `a shouldEqual b.sorted.reverse` and also a type without a default order/ordering instance, such as `java.util.OffsetDatetime`.

Comment: Do you mean something like `a shouldBeReversedSorted`? where `shouldBeReversedSorted` would be a custom function you customize for reusability?

Comment: Ideally `shouldBe sortedBy(implicit o : Ordering[_])`.

Comment: What'd you end up doing?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar No solution so far. You could just use shouldEqual and manually sort.